# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (24500, 50, 50, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_34:0', which has shape '(?, 2500)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This is the cat vs dog problem from kaggle competition. My code is look like correct but still a value error annoying me. I think I have given the correct size of the input but still the error comes.
Please help me to find out the error.
Here's my full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import shuffle
import tensorflow
from tqdm import tqdm                                                       

TRAIN_DIR = 'C:\\Users\Kashif\PycharmProjects\DeepLearning-Tensorflow (Sentdex)\Learnings\Cat_VS_Dog\TrainingData'
TEST_DIR = 'C:\\Users\Kashif\PycharmProjects\DeepLearning-Tensorflow (Sentdex)\Learnings\Cat_VS_Dog\TestingData'
IMG_SIZE = 50

MODEL_NAME = 'dogvscat-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')


def label_img(img):
    word_label = img.split('.')[-3]
    if word_label == 'cat': return [1,0]
    elif word_label == 'dog': return [0,1]


def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img),np.array(label)])
    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
    return training_data


def process_test_data():
    testing_data=[]
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):
        path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR, img)
        img_num = img.split('.')[0]
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),  (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        testing_data.append([np.array(img), img_num])

    np.save('test_data.npy', testing_data)
    return testing_data


train_data = create_train_data()


learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 10
batch_size = 128
n_classes = 2

drop_out = 0.8
filter_h_w = 5
depth_in = 1
depth_out_1 = 32
depth_out_2 = 64

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, IMG_SIZE * IMG_SIZE])
y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_classes])

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def maxpool2d(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

def conv_nural_network(x):

    weights = {
               'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filter_h_w, filter_h_w, depth_in, depth_out_1])),
               'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filter_h_w, filter_h_w, depth_out_1, depth_out_2])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([ int(IMG_SIZE/4) * int(IMG_SIZE/4) * depth_out_2, 1024])),
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))
              }

    biases = {
              'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([depth_out_1])),
              'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([depth_out_2])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
             }

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, int(IMG_SIZE/4) * int(IMG_SIZE/4) * depth_out_2])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, drop_out)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return output



train = train_data[:-500]
test = train_data[-500:]

train_X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
train_y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_X = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]



def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = conv_nural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    loss_trace = []
    accuracy_trace = []

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for i in range(epochs):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: train_X, y: train_y})
            loss = sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={x: train_X, y: train_y})
            accuracy = np.mean(np.argmax(sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={x:train_X,y:train_y}),axis=1) == np.argmax(train_y,axis=1))
            loss_trace.append(loss)
            accuracy_trace.append(accuracy)
            print('Epoch:', (i + 1), 'loss:', loss, 'accuracy:', accuracy)

        print('Final training result:', 'loss:', loss, 'accuracy:', accuracy)
        loss_test = sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={x: test_X, y: test_y})
        test_pred = np.argmax(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: test_X, y: test_y}), axis=1)
        accuracy_test = np.mean(test_pred == np.argmax(test_y, axis=1))
        print('Results on test dataset:', 'loss:', loss_test, 'accuracy:', accuracy_test)


train_neural_network(x)
```

This error comes after that. A value error has come but I don't know where I have given the wrong input type.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-7682c5a4d0ec> in <module>
     25 
     26 
---> 27 train_neural_network(x)

<ipython-input-91-7682c5a4d0ec> in train_neural_network(x)
     11         sess.run(init)
     12         for i in range(epochs):
---> 13             sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: train_X, y: train_y})
     14             loss = sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={x: train_X, y: train_y})
     15             accuracy = np.mean(np.argmax(sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={x:train_X,y:train_y}),axis=1) == np.argmax(train_y,axis=1))


ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (24500, 50, 50, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_34:0', which has shape '(?, 2500)'
```

Comment: You define placeholder x as `x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, IMG_SIZE * IMG_SIZE])`, which is 50*50=2500 and None is for batch size. And trying to feed all of your 24500 examples to it as is. You need to create batches. And why do you trying to feed flatten data to convolutional layer, which expects 4 dimensions as input

Comment: Hi i think you defined your x wrong.
try
`x=tf.placeholder('float', [None, IMG_SIZE , IMG_SIZE,1])`
as None is your batchsize and img_size for each dimension of your image.

Comment: I have sent the data in batches now but still the same kind of error comes. And If I change my placeholder x to x=tf.placeholder('float', [None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1]), then a run time error occurs and my kernal has stopped working.